When is $\text{Ab}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ monadic?
Consider the free abelian group monad $T: \text{Sets} \to \text{Sets}$. Then the category $\text{Ab}$ of abelian groups is equivalent to the category of $T$-algebras, and thus we have a monadic (forgetful) functor $\text{Ab}\to \text{Sets}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite products. Then we can form the category of abelian group objects $\text{Ab}(\mathcal{C})$. In the case $\mathcal{C} = \text{Sets}$, we have a monadic functor $\text{Ab}(\text{Sets}) \to \text{Sets}$ because of the equivalence $\text{Ab}(\text{Sets}) \approx \text{Ab}$.
In general, what are the conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\text{Ab}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ is monadic? I am imagining that there may be some conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ such that $T: \text{Sets} \to \text{Sets}$ can be "lifted" to $T': \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ in such a way that the category of $T'$-algebras is $\text{Ab}(\mathcal{C})$.

Not a complete answer, just what seem to me to be the obvious plans of attack. I think a sufficient condition is going to end up being that $C$ admits colimits and products distribute over colimits (this happens for example in any cocomplete cartesian closed category, e.g. any Grothendieck topos), but I don't feel confident about the details. The idea is that we can try to explicitly define the free abelian group object functor using only products and colimits. Let's do this in stages: first, the free monoid is easy to construct, it is the "list monad"
$$F_{\text{Mon}}(c) \cong \bigsqcup_{n \ge 0} c^n.$$
This is the "geometric series" $\frac{1}{1 - c}$. Next, the free commutative monoid is only a little harder to construct, it is
$$F_{\text{CMon}}(c) \cong \bigsqcup_{n \ge 0} \frac{c^n}{S_n}$$
where the notation refers to the quotient of $c^n$ by the action of the symmetric group $S_n$. This is the "exponential" $\exp(c)$.
The free abelian group is a little trickier but I think the following should work, maybe with extra hypotheses on $C$. First we consider the free commutative monoid $F_{\text{CMon}}(c \sqcup c^{-1})$ on two copies of $c$, one of which is the "inverses." Next, we need to quotient this by the equivalence relation generated by the requirement that $c^{-1}$ actually acts as the object of inverses of $c$; formally this is some suitable coequalizer or coequalizers.
But I don't actually know a nice way to prove that this construction really is the left adjoint to the forgetful functor; maybe someone else knows how to work through the details but it seems tricky to me.
So we could take a different and more abstract approach. Namely, we could instead verify the hypotheses of the adjoint functor theorem, then the monadicity theorem. It is getting late but I can try to come back to this tomorrow and see what that looks like.

Alternately, in any topos with a natural numbers object, you could do a similar construction using the internal language.

For the free abelian group step, it seems like you should be able to internalize the Grothendieck group construction as the coequalizer of two maps from an equalizer to $M^2$, representing ${ (a,b,c,d,e) \mid a+d+e = b+c+e } \mapsto (a,b), (c,d)$.
